# How to update network-manager-openvpn to latest version in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I need to use a VPN which requires a version of Network Manager OpenVPN 1.2.x.

The command `dpkg -l network-manager-openvpn-gnome` has the following output -

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                      Version                   Architecture              Description
+++-=========================================-=========================-=========================-=========================================================
ii  network-manager-openvpn-gnome             1.1.93-1ubuntu1.1         amd64                     network management framework (OpenVPN plugin GNOME GUI)
```

I realize that this might be a newbie question but how do I update the plugin to the latest version? Thankyou.

Comment: Two means: 1) Unofficial repo, 2) build from source...